# Is there a tool similar to the Web.config transformation tool that I can use on xml in general?

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I've been having to perform changes to a handful of xml configuration files which is tedious and error prone. I was wondering if there was a tool available like the web.config transformation tool that I could use to transform regular xml with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool for changing xml files is [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the web.config transformation tool, so I can not say if they are similar.

Comment: I'm aware of XSLT, but is there anything that will execute those transforms for me without having to write code to do it?

Comment: @Dave - you want magical transformations that read your mind?

Comment: command line maybe? c:\>transform my.xml with-this.xslt > output-to-this.xml

Comment: Google "XSLT Command Line" result 1: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html